# How to make billing address entry compulsory when Paypal is used?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, paypal, paypal-express

When Paypal is used as the payment method, entry of the billing address becomes not compulsory.

You will see on the screenshot below, that the billing address is empty and the "Continue to Paypal" button is active.

How to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try: "Require Customer's Billing Address" to Yes, in the payment method configuration?

Comment: The way you are suggesting, the billing address is requested from Paypal, not entered on the website.